# jQuery UI Slider move forward and backward with external controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to make the UI slider with range to move forward and backward with the external controls I'm creating based on the Seconds clicked in the controls

I want to move Start and Endpoints to forward and backward, when i click 1S forward the startPoint should move forward 1Second, same like for 5S forward. When i click 1S backward the EndpOint should move to 1S backward same thing happens to 5S Backward

I have created fiddle to work around for this

HTML :

```
<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>
<div id="slider"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span id="slider-value"></span></p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="time-change" data-id="5" data-value="dec" >5S </a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="time-change" data-id="1" data-value="dec" >1S </a></li>
</ul>
<div class="play-pause-btn"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="play-pause" id="play-pause" ></a></div>
<div class="forward-blk">
<ul class="">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="time-change" data-id="1" data-value="inc"  > 1S</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="time-change" data-id="5" data-value="inc"  >5S</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS :

```
 $(".time-change").bind("click", function() {
        var ttype=$(this).data('value');
        var dtime=parseInt($(this).data('id'));
        if($("#slider" ))
             {
            var curstart =  $("#slider").slider("option", "values")[0];
            var curstop = $("#slider").slider("option", "values")[1];
             }
        if (ttype=="inc") {

             if($("#slider" ))
             {
                 var incTime= dtime;
                 //$( ".cut-slider" ).slider( "option", "min", curstart );
                 $( ".cut-slider" ).slider( "option", "values", [ incTime, curstop ] );
             }
        }else{

            if($("#slider"))
             {  
       var decTime= dtime;  
                //$( ".cut-slider" ).slider( "option", "max", curstop );
                $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "values", [ curstart, decTime ] );      

             }
        }
        });
```

Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj4hL8gu/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `values` have to be in the `min-max` range (inclusive). If you don't increase or decrease the slider `values` using the value defined in `step`, you will experience undesired behaviour. In your case, setting the value to anything greater than or equal to 1 is invalid, since the `max` is `0.5`.

What you need to do is set the `values` property to `[0, 0.5]`, which is your range. When you increase or decrease the range steps, you need to use increments of `0.01`:

```
$(".time-change").bind("click", function() {
  var ttype = $(this).data('value');
  var dtime = parseInt($(this).data('id'));
  if ($("#slider")) {
    var curstart = $("#slider").slider("option", "values")[0];
    var curstop = $("#slider").slider("option", "values")[1];
  }

  var stepValue;
  //Make sure handle 1 doesn't pass handle 2 (remove this if you want to allow passing)
  if (ttype == "inc" && curstart < curstop - step) {
    curstart = curstart + (step * dtime);
  } else if (ttype == "dec" && curstop > curstart + step) { //Make sure handle 2 doesn't pass handle 1 (remove this if you want to allow passing)
    curstop = curstop - (step * dtime);
  }
  $("#slider").slider("option", "values", [curstart, curstop]);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj4hL8gu/13/)**

Comment: Well try, but you see sliders are crossing each others, which is not correct. i mean start point going beyond end point

Comment: Do you mean the overlap? Where the handles appear over each other?

Comment: Great , still am wondering that the forward only working, i can't see any backward action for the handlebars

Comment: The backward action is for the second handle. Do you want the forward and backward action just for the first handle?

Comment: i want both Handlers to be Forward and when each other hits the same value both should backward when we click the controls further

Comment: @JothiKannan Please see my updated fiddle. If you now press the "increase" options, both handles move up to a certain point and stop. Once they stop, you have to use the "decrease" options to go back.

Comment: Great, highly appreciate your help on this, I need final fix, is it possible to stop the slider 1Second before it meets each other ? i mean i don't want merge both Handlres same place ?

Comment: Please check the updated fiddle and let me know if it's okay.

Comment: its ok, by when i click forward both Handlers are moving, which is not before

Comment: Please be clear in your requirements. I'm not sure what the problem is? You did say in a previous comment that you wanted both handles to move.